# Find category within category model - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, controller

When a category is deleted, contents/posts with same `category_id` also needs be destroyed.

Here is my categories controller.

```
#Categories Controller

def destroy
    authorize @category
    @category.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to categories_url, notice: 'Category was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

    def set_category
      @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    end

    def category_params
      params.require(:category).permit(:title, :user_id, :image)
    end
```

Inside my Category model, I have added a `after_destory`.

```
#Category model
    
      after_destroy :remove_content

  private

  def remove_content
    if Content.exists?(:category_id => self.id)
      Content.destroy(the_content)
    end
  end


  def the_content
    @the_content = Content.where(category_id: self.id)
  end
```

I use `self.id` to grab `category_id`, but the category uses id and title as uri.

```
  def to_param
    "#{id} #{title}".parameterize
  end
```

Content belongs to category.

```
#Content model
class Content < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "300x160#", thumb: "100x53#" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category

  def to_param
    "#{id} #{title}".parameterize
  end

end
```

How can I grab `category_id` from CategoriesController without `self.id` ?

Comment: can u post code of Content model? @Nævid Urfriend

Comment: Added the content model

Comment: why u didn't used " belongs_to :category:dependent => :destroy " in Content model??

Comment: @NarasimhaReddy - That will destroy category every time content is destroyed - having that category can have many contents it can cause some, well, serious issues.

Comment: Thank you @BroiSatse. i am also new to RoR.

Comment: @NarasimhaReddy Thanks for your pointer as BroiSatse says it would that destroy category. See the answer that BroiSatse wrote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use association for this:

```
classs Category < ActiveReocrd::Base

  has_many :contents, dependent: :destroy
```

`dependend: :destroy` does exactly what you are trying to achieve. It adds a hook destroying all the contents which belongs to deleted category. Note, do not use `@category.delete` as it is not triggering any hooks - always use `@category.destroy`

Comment: I am noob in rails, Could you please explain what the dependent: :destroy did that i could just pass @category? Tnx

Comment: I'll explain for you if you want

Comment: I would Thank you for that :)

Answer (score 0):

Like what `BroiStaste` said, you'd be best using the `dependent: :destroy` switch in the `Category` model:

```
#app/models/category.rb
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :contents, dependent: :destroy
```

This is a very simple principle, in that you're telling ActiveRecord that if you destroy a `Category` object (which is what you're doing), it should destroy any of the `dependent` `Content` objects it has.

From the [Docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-dependent):

> If you set the `:dependent` option to:
>
> `:destroy`, when the object is destroyed, destroy will be called on its associated objects.
> `:delete`, when the object is destroyed, all its associated objects will be deleted directly from the database without calling their destroy method.

Comment: Thank you so much @RickPeck. As said, I am noob in Rails (a good noob ;) ) and looking for a mentor that can give me pointers sometimes. It could be great if you could. Tnx